# Windows 11 bluescreen after update, cannot acess my files (bitlocker)

Tags: bsod, windows-11, bitlocker

After turning on a windows feature, my Windows 11 restarted and now I'm stuck with bluescreen.
While booting, Bitlocker asks me for my pin code and then I bluescreen during Windows' boot process.
I have Bitlocker with TPM + Pin Code. I know my Pin code, but I do not have my recovery key.
I tried:

- Go to troubleshooting > Adminitrator CMD: `Manage-bde -unlock C: -user` doesn't work.
- I tried to boot on Linux live USB and use `dislocker`, same.

Is there anything I can do for at least recover my files? As I said I know the Pin and I can still use it but that leads to a BSOD. I don't have the recovery key.

Comment: How do you do troubleshooting if you can't boot?

Comment: I can reach the troubleshooting from the Bitlocker's menu if I press the escape key two times I think ; or also sometimes after 1 or 2 BSOD, right after entering my pin code to unclock Bitlocker, windows is printing a message like it detects something went wrong and boot on a menu where you can choose to continue, choose a device, troubleshoot, advanced options

Comment: If you use a Microsoft account (hard not to under Windows 11), you may log to the web and find your recovery key in there : [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6).

Comment: Indeed I didn't mention that, but I do not have a microsoft acccount. My recovery key isn't on their server

Comment: Tough. You may try some more methods [here](https://iboysoft.com/bitlocker/unlock-bitlocker-without-password-recovery-key.html).

Comment: Without the recovery key there isn’t anything that can be done

Comment: If you go around 3 times, do you get the option to boot to the recovery console?

Comment: It's quite sad really, that in the past decade we've gone from people waiting until their drive fails before wondering how to rescue their life's work…  to people now actively locking themselves out of any potential recovery effort. *Backups*, people… *backups*. …& remember to store your recovery key somewhere you can get to it if the drive fails.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue many times as a computer tech. Unfortunately without a recovery key tied to a MS account, there is no way to access the encrypted files. The only course of action would be to reinstall Windows via an installer disk/USB.